# If the EM field is a self-propagating field that doesn't need a media why should space expansion make any changes to its wavelength?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, space-expansion, aether

If the EM field is a self-propagating field that doesn't need a media why should space expansion make any changes to its wavelength? If it makes changes to the photons wavelength should it be considered as the field propagator as the photons spread away from each other according how much space streched along the photons path?

Comment: The uniform space expansion without acceleration does not change the wavelength of light. The cosmological redshift is caused by observing light from a different frame of reference, not by photons losing energy. Your question is based on a wrong premise.

Answer (score 0):

In general relativity it is important to separate in your mind coordinate-dependent effects from coordinate-independent effects. This can be tricky, particularly in scenarios where there is a “standard” coordinate system. In those cases it is easy to forget that the standard coordinate system is still just a coordinate system.

In this case, the standard coordinate system is the comoving coordinates. This system of coordinates has the weird property that two distant objects which are each at rest in these coordinates are moving away from each other in a coordinate independent sense. The observed redshift is a reflection of that coordinate independent fact.

It is possible to write the laws of electromagnetism in these coordinates and show that there is a strange wavelength-stretching term. However, the utility of doing that is dubious. I recommend sticking to coordinate independent explanations whenever feasible, as it is here.